# Rows concatenation in a big data.frame

Tags: r

I have a simple question. The data.frame I have to analyze looks like this:

> ```
>  a     o    34   c    456    d    32   r    21
>  a     s    21   f    78     
>  s     z    21   df    4     m    21        
>  t     x    2    vb   20     p    34   q    56   g   65
>  d     n    78   oi   43     w   322   y    123
>  d     q    76   gh   0.9    wt   3
> ```

I simply would like the following output:

> ```
>  a     o    34   c    456    d    32   r    21  s 21  f 78  
>  s     z    21   df    4     m    21        
>  t     x    2    vb   20     p    34   q   56   g 65
>  d     n    78   oi   43     w   322   y   123  q 76  gh   0.9    wt   3
> ```

In other words the line starting with "a" is replicated so the second line named "a" will be attached to the first line named "a" regardless the order of words or numbers (ascending or descending). The same with "d". I tried considering the frequencies of "a", "s", "t", "d", using the function "table", but i'm not able to go on after considering the frequency since I'm new in R.

> dput(head(tmp1))

Output:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(38L, 37L, 14L, 26L, 35L, 9L), .Label = c("AATF", 
"C14orf143", "CCDC57", "CLNS1A", "DSCC1", "ENOPH1", "EXOSC2", 
"FARSA", "FASN", "FKBP4", "FTSJ3", "GUF1", "HSPA4", "HSPA9", 
"IFRD2", "LARP4", "MAZ", "MECR", "NARS2", "NAT10", "NFS1", "NLE1", 
"NUP107", "PLA2G12A", "POLD2", "POLR3K", "PPP5C", "PSME3", "RAE1", 
"RET", "RNF126", "SFXN1", "SLC24A3", "SLC25A15", "THOP1", "TIMM13", 
"TMEM93", "TP53I11", "TRAP1", "WDR18", "WDR61"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(24L, 21L, 14L, 25L, 27L, 26L),.......), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You probably want to use lists rather than data frames for this. Also, what does your data *actually* look like? Could you post `dput(head(your_data))`?

Comment: I just edited with a small piece of the dput(head(tmp1)) output since the data.frame is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DF <- read.delim(text=" a     o    34   c    456    d    32   r    21
 a     s    21   f    78     
 s     z    21   df    4     m    21        
 t     x    2    vb   20     p    34   q    56   g   65
 d     n    78   oi   43     w   322   y    123
 d     q    76   gh   0.9    wt   3",fill=TRUE,sep=" ",header=FALSE)



library(plyr)

dlply(DF,.(V2),function(x) { 
  res <- as.character(na.omit(do.call(c,as.data.frame(t(x[,-2])))))
  res <- res[res!=""]
  res
                             })

$a
 [1] "o"   "34"  "c"   "456" "d"   "32"  "r"   "21"  "s"   "21"  "f"   " 78"

$d
 [1] "n"    "78"   "oi"   "43.0" "w"    "322"  "y"    "123"  "q"    "76"   "gh"   " 0.9"
[13] "wt"   " 3"  

$s
[1] "z"  "21" "df" "4"  "m"  "21"

$t
 [1] "x"  "2"  "vb" "20" "p"  "34" "q"  "56" "g"  "65"
```